# Can there be a strict transaction that is not 2Phase?

Tags: terminology, database-theory

I am confused about the definition of a strict transaction. What is the difference between a transaction that is strict and a transaction that is both strict and 2 phase?

Answer (score 2):

Strictness Strictness ($\textsf{ST}$) is related to recoverability. Serializability ($\textsf{SR}$) is one of many consistency conditions of transactions, which is somewhat orthogonal to recoverability. 2PL is a protocol usually used to ensure serializability.

First, I don't think the term "strict transaction" is proper. Strictness, just like serializability, is defined over executions (also called histories or schedules) of transactions.

Secondly, strictness is *incomparable* to serializability (there are various versions of serializability. I suppose you are referring to CSR --- conflict serializability).

Finally, your question "Can there be a strict transaction that is not 2Phase?" should be

> "Is there any execution which is strict but not serializable?"

The answer is "Yes". For example, $e = r_1(x) \; w_2(x) \; w_2(y) \; c_2 \; r_1(y) \; c_1$. You can check that $e \in \textsf{ST} \land e \notin \textsf{SR}$.